# Изменение окна PictureBox пропорционально окну формы

Tags: c#, winforms, окно

Как можно сделать так, чтобы при изменении размера окна формы размер PictureBox увеличивался пропорционально окну формы?

Answer (score 1):

Выдели PictureBox....

Задай Anchor в Properties твоего PictureBox на все стороны